# Non recursive code going recursive

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, recursion, tree

The following code should create a simple "tree", but it becomes recursive and crashes.

```
        var cnt = 0;
        var page = {
            properties: {},
            folders: [],
            items: []
        };

        function createPage() {
            var ret = $.extend({}, page);
            ret.cnt = cnt++;
            return  ret;
        }
        var tree = createPage();

        function addFolders(f, n) {
            for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) {
                f.push(createPage());
            }
        }


        function createData() {
            addFolders(tree.folders, 4);
            for (var i = 0; i < tree.folders.length; i++) {
                addFolders(tree.folders[i].folders, i);
            }
        }

        createData();
```

Can someone please explain why this is happening?

Comment: Im confused about `$.extend({}, page);` what is this doing?

Comment: Your `$.extend` is not doing a deep copy, so the subfolders are always a reference to the same root folders. Do this `var ret = $.extend(true, {}, page);` or just use an object literal directly in `createPage()`.

Comment: @squint but, since it's using an empty object as target, it actually creates a copy.. not a reference.

Comment: It only makes a shallow copy. The properties that reference two arrays and an object are not copied. Those are references.

Comment: @Black a jquery function that copies an object, here i use it to clone an object and not referring to it recursively (maybe i'm doing it wrong)

Comment: ...to test, put `console.log(page.folders.length)` inside `createPage()`. You'll see that the `folders` of the *original* `page` object is mutated. Good idea to have a counter that throws an error when it reaches `100` or something so that it doesn't infinitely recurse. Also, use the developer tools to step through the code as it runs.

Comment: @squint
from the documentation:

`If, however, you want to preserve both of the original objects, you can do so by passing an empty object as the target:
1
 

var object = $.extend({}, object1, object2);`

Comment: @yossi: Yes, the original *outer* object is preserved at a *shallow* level. But you're not just mutating the outer object; you're mutating the objects that the outer objects reference. That's why there's the `deep` option, which I showed above.

Comment: @squint
i understood your explanation, and verified it (using the deep option) i just don't understand why. the example that jquery gave - is supposed NO to clone. am i wrong?

Comment: It only clones the outer object, not the nested objects. So when you push to `.folders` of the copy, you're pushing to `.folders` of the original, because it didn't copy it; it assigned a reference to the outer copy. Here's a simpler demo: https://jsfiddle.net/zazvkvmh/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

squint is right, the script is always pushing to the same `folders` array, causing the length to keep increasing and never getting out of the loop. You can change the `createPage` function to this:

```
function createPage() {
  return {
      properties: {},
      cnt: cnt++,
      folders: [],
      items: []
  };
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`$.extend({}, page);` does a shallow copy of `page` object.

```
var secondPage = $.extend({}, page);
console.log(page === secondPage); // false
console.log(page.folders === secondPage.folders); // true!!
```

As `createData` is looping over `tree.folders` it is also modifying it so on every iteration `tree.folders.length` only increases.

You can pass in an additional option to `$.extend` to [do a deep extend](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.extend/#jQuery-extend-deep-target-object1-objectN) `$.extend(true, {}, page)`

```
var secondPage = $.extend(true, {}, page);
console.log(page === secondPage); // false
console.log(page.folders === secondPage.folders); // false
```

Answer (score 1):

**The problem:** 
Your `$.extend` is not doing a deep copy, so the subfolders are always a reference to the same root folders. Do this `var ret = $.extend(true, {}, page);` or just use an object literal directly in `createPage()`. It only makes a shallow copy. The properties that reference two arrays and an object are not copied. Those are references.

**To replicate/test:**
Put `console.log(page.folders.length)` inside `createPage()`. You'll see that the `folders` of the original `page` object is mutated. Good idea to have a counter that throws an error when it reaches `100` or something so that it doesn't infinitely recurse. Also, use the developer tools to step through the code as it runs.

**The solution:**
The original outer object is preserved at a shallow level. But you're not just mutating the outer object; you're mutating the objects that the outer objects reference. That's why there's the `deep` option, which I showed above. So when you push to `.folders` of the copy, you're pushing to `.folders` of the original, because it didn't copy it; it assigned a reference to the outer copy.

Here's a simpler demo: [jsfiddle.net/zazvkvmh](http://jsfiddle.net/zazvkvmh)